# how to specify has_many through vs has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-many

So I'm trying to figure out how to specify between calling all instances of an object based on the has_many and has_many :through associations. I have users, groups and members. the member model is a pairing of groups and users. the groups also have a user_id in that model. so this will make more sense after you see the code:

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end
```

group model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through => :members
    belongs_to :user
end
```

member model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :groups
  belongs_to :users
end
```

Index View

```
<!--these are the groups I own (the group.user_id is my id) NEEDS EDITING-->
  <% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <%= link_to group.title, group_path(group) %>
      <%= truncate group.desc %>
  <% end %>

<!--I'm a member of these groups (connected through the member model) NEEDS EDITING'-->
  <% current_user.groups.order(:created_at).each do |group| %>
      <%= link_to group.title, group_path(group) %>
      <%= truncate group.desc %>
  <% end %>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to call the different types of associations users and groups in the Index View.

I want to get a list of all the groups that have me listed as admin (group.user_id) and then I want to get a separate list of all the groups that I'm a member of (through the member model).

I know I can query it with a find or where call. However, I was hoping there was a simple way like current_user.groups or something. anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider calling the 1:N relationship to groups another name. So you would end up with something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :owned_groups, class_name: 'Group'
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end
```

So the index view would look something like:

```
<% current_user.owned_groups.each do |group| %>
    <%= link_to group.title, group_path(group) %>
    <%= truncate group.desc %>
<% end %>


<% current_user.groups.order(:created_at).each do |group| %>
    <%= link_to group.title, group_path(group) %>
    <%= truncate group.desc %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok, I think I understand but I'm confused by 1:N. what does that mean exactly? Also, would owned_groups be a separate model? or does does that "class_name: 'Group'" route the owned_groups back to the groups model? I've never seen that before, thats cool

Comment: ok, I implemented this change but I get a strange error "Could not find the association :members in model User" and yet in my user model I have: "  has_many :groups, :through => :members" ALSO, this error highlights the line: "current_user.groups.order...."

Comment: Sorry, by 1:N I mean the "one to many" relationship between a User and the Groups she owns. The N:N relationship would between a User and Groups through the Members table.

Comment: Oh of course, thanks, I now get a different error on the same line of code: uninitialized constant User::Groups. 

I think this is because the name is the same as the Class_name "group" so is there a way to add class_name 'member' to has many :groups, through members association line. I'm going to try that

Comment: omg, after trying like 100 different things I think I ended back up at this solution to fix the uninitialized constant error and I fixed the member class to be singular belong tos. that was it I think, incase anyone has this problem. thanks GSP!